# After about 80 cycles between two activities the device gets restarted

Tags: android

I have three Activities (first, second and third).
The app starts with the first Activity, then the app moves to the second one, and when the player finishes it, the app moves to the third one and then goes back to the second one and continues with this cycle between the second and the third ones.
After about 80 or 90 cycles, the device will restart.
I think maybe there is a cache for Activities that is overflowing.

What is the problem, and could anyone help me?

Here is a sample of all the three Activities.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =
            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams superparams =
            new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        //sakhte tablelayout
        TableLayout supertable = new TableLayout(this);
        supertable.setLayoutParams(superparams);
        supertable.setOrientation(TableLayout.VERTICAL);

        TableRow table = new TableRow(this);
        ImageButton start = new ImageButton(this);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent("net.learn2develop.SecondTurn");
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        start.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        start.setLayoutParams(params);

        setContentView(supertable);
        supertable.addView(table);
        table.addView(start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the Manifest it's hard to tell, but, depending on the launch mode, you are creating 80 activities, that kind of burns the device a lot. Either call finish, or set the activities to be singletop.

Comment: Please, add your manifest configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably aren't calling finish() when you are moving between two and three.
Also you should look at the intent flag clear top to clear any old activities.
Also my suggestion is to use a single fragment activity and keep changing a fragment instead of the whole activity.

Comment: if i don't use finish(),is activity stay alive?but i call again that with new variables.

Comment: if you don't use finish the activity is only put to pause and not destroyed. the system destroys it if it is running low on resources, but  you can rely on that to happen... always clean stuff you no longer need. But as I suspected, you should use fragments. A flow like this will be better for you. MainActivity -> SecondActivity (which extends FragmentActivity). SecondActivity shows fragment and when you would normaly go to the third activity, just replace current fragment with the new one and vice versa.